# How to read DBF file that contain thai wording in C#

Tags: c#, dbf

I have a dbf file which contains thai language in some column. But when I convert it into Data Table, it become unreadable wording.

```
 var oConn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
            oConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=" + dbPath + ";";
            oConn.Open();
            var oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();
            oCmd.CommandText = "SELECT badgename FROM " + dbPath + @"\BADGE.DBF";
            var reader = oCmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            byte[] A = Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding.Default.CodePage).GetBytes(reader.GetString(0));
            string p = Encoding.Unicode.GetString((Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding(874), Encoding.Unicode, A)));
```

I also tried to change machine locale to Thai, but still cannot solve my problem. 
Please help.

Comment: I able to convert but still a bit different with original word where I will get few '?' in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you need is: **Unicode**. Try this code.

```
var oConn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
oConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=" + dbPath;
oConn.Open();
var oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();
oCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT name FROM " + dbPath + "TABLE.DBF";
var reader = oCmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read(); 
byte[] A = Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding.Default.CodePage).GetBytes(reader.GetString(0));
string p = Encoding.Unicode.GetString((Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding(850), Encoding.Unicode, A)));
```

Comment: I still using the OleDbConnection, but then foreach row by row to convert the column, but still cannot convert to correct value.

Comment: Did you try FoxPro Driver?

Comment: You mean this one right?
http://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=14839

Comment: Just tried the ODBC one, but still getting the same problem.

Comment: Please edit your actual question by appending what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your connection string the following parameter:

```
CODEPAGE=874;
```

where 874 is the codepage for Thai Windows encoding.

If this won't help, try Barry Guvenkaya's conversion to Unicode using 874 codepage instead of 850.